# How to create download link in a webpage i develop using Java,JSP

Tags: jsp

In the website I am developing, i wish other users to download files present in my computer (server). I wish to create download links for those files using JSP technology.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: <a href="...">? Nothing special about jsp...

Comment: Do you have to secure those files, i.e. can only users with certain priviliges download them? If so, you need something like a proxy servlet, verifying that the user is authorized and then stream the file back.

Answer (score 2):

I think [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/) is a good example for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

in a tag .. href="pathfromrootdir/filename.extension"